# How to register the ID and the count (or number) of occurrences in a sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python so bear with me, please. I have been asked to create a program. I need to look for occurrences of a pattern (which has to be provided by the user using the keyboard) string inside each of the sequences and if there are occurrences, register the id and the number (count) of occurrences in the sequence.

The data looks like this:

```
id  sequence
1   MVLSEGEWAAVLHVWAKVEADVAAGHGQDILIRLFKS
2   MNIFEMLRIAAGLRLKIYKDTEAAGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSL
3   MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFKSH
4   MNIFEMLRAAEGAALRLKIYKAADTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKS
5   MVLSAAEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFK
```

where the ids are the numbers and the sequence are the sequences below each number. The file is a matrix of (100437 x 2)

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import re

def proteins_pattern_count(pattern):
    with open("proteins.csv", 'r') as proteins:
        proteins = proteins.read()
        items = re.findall(pattern, proteins)
    return len(items)

# Reading the pattern to look for and forcing the input to change the pattern to capital letters.
pattern = input("Please type in the pattern you would like to look for: ").upper()

count = proteins_pattern_count(pattern)

print('The pattern {} appears {} times within the proteins file'.format(pattern, count))
```

Output that I get:

```
Please type in the pattern you would like to look for: AA
The pattern AA appears 173372 times within the proteins file
```

But what I really want is: for instance, if the pattern I am looking for is "AA" then I would like to see a table only with the ids of the sequences that actually have such pattern inside and the number (count) of occurrences in the sequence, like this:

```
id  count
1   2
2   2
4   3
5   1
```

I think this is very easy to do, but I'm completely new to Python.

Thanks for your support!!

Comment: After opening your file, you should use proteins.readlines() and iterate your findall method over each element of the created list. You can use the idx of the list which correspond to your `id - 1`

Comment: @Clément How do you know the all the ids in the real data increment by one in ascending order?

Comment: We can't. Otherwise if id's are not sorted you still can read the id information using the first char if the read line.

Comment: @Clément That would only work if all the ids are a single number, which seems unlikely, no? Also, the header line needs special handling. So the correct way to read the file is using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Comment: Thanks guys, the id numbers are actually consecutive from 1 to 100436.

Comment: @ekhumoro That was implicit but the idea was to split the line using "\t" character which seems to be used to split the Id from the sequence.

Comment: @Clément See the accepted answer, which uses the csv module, as I recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would highly recommend using a different variable name for your object returned by `.readlines()`, as currently you are overwriting your file pointer. While it isn't necessary for this code, it's good practice in general.

Second, to make things easier, you may wish to use `csv.reader` to split up your csv in a nice, easy fashion.

Here are three code snippets you can use:

```
import re, csv

def proteins_slow1(pattern):
    with open("proteins.csv", 'r') as fp:
        proteins = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
        ids, counts = [], []
        for i,seq in proteins:
            count = len(re.findall(pattern, seq))
            if count != 0:
                ids.append(i)
                counts.append(count)
    return ids, counts

def proteins_slow2(pattern):
    with open("proteins.csv", 'r') as fp:
        proteins = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
        struct = {}
        for i,seq in proteins:
            count = len(re.findall(pattern, seq))
            if count != 0:
                struct[i] = count
    return struct

def proteins_fast(pattern):
    with open("proteins.csv", 'r') as fp:
        proteins = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
        struct = {}
        for i,seq in proteins:
            count = seq.count(pattern)
            if count != 0:
                struct[i] = count
    return struct
```

`proteins_slow1` makes two lists, and appends them if the count is non-zero. The function ends by returning a tuple with the `ids` list and the `counts` list.

This is pretty much as fast as `proteins_slow2`, which makes a dictionary, and adds new entries as key-value pairs (id as the key, count as the value).

The quickest is to actually not use `re` but instead use the `.count()` method on the sequence string. This shaves off about 30-40% off the running time (which will become important if you're repeatedly looking at 100000+ rows).

```
>>> %timeit proteins_slow1('AA')
199 ms ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>> %timeit proteins_slow2('AA')
187 ms ± 767 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>> %timeit proteins_fast('AA')
119 ms ± 539 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

(Timing tests were done by making a csv file from the following function:)

```
def writer():
    with open("proteins.csv", 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        proteins = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')

        for i in range(20000):
            proteins.writerow([str(0+i*5),'MVLSEGEWAAVLHVWAKVEADVAAGHGQDILIRLFKS'])
            proteins.writerow([str(1+i*5),'MNIFEMLRIAAGLRLKIYKDTEAAGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSL'])
            proteins.writerow([str(2+i*5),'MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFKSH'])
            proteins.writerow([str(3+i*5),'MNIFEMLRAAEGAALRLKIYKAADTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKS'])
            proteins.writerow([str(4+i*5),'MVLSAAEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFK'])
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
res = {}
for protein in proteins.readlines():
    if pattern in protein:
        res[protein[0]] = protein.count(pattern)

print(res)
```